# How to loop the datetime in mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, for-loop

im using mysql stored procedure, how can I make a loop that in every 1 hour the variable strathour will have 1 hour interval then return the ouptut of the query which is total. While the starthour is less than the date of november it will have interval of 1 hour and perform the query.

here's my code:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `sp_asessiontime`(
out `total` int
)
BEGIN

declare `starthour`, `endhour` datetime;
set `starthour` = '2012-09-20 01:59:00';
set `endhour` = '2012-09-20 02:00:00';


select count(terminalcount.terminalids) into total from (
select distinct ts.TerminalID `terminalids` from
tmptransactiondetails td
inner join transactionsummary ts
on td.TransactionSummaryID = ts.TransactionsSummaryID
where
td.ServiceID = 4
and
td.TransactionType in ('D','W')
and
(ts.DateStarted >= starthour and ts.DateStarted < endhour)
or
(ts.DateEnded >= starthour and ts.DateEnded < endhour)
or
(ts.DateStarted < starthour and starthour <= ts.DateEnded)
)as terminalcount;
```

-- loop for every 1 hour

```
while 

starthour < '2012-11-01 01:59:00' do
select starthour + interval 1 hour;
select total as totalnumber;

end while;

END
```

Thank you so much guys.

Comment: I wish someone could help me :(

Answer (score 10):

I am not sure I got your question correctly, but this is how you loop between dates

```
set currHour = '2012-09-20 01:59:00';
set endhour = '2012-09-21 02:00:00';

REPEAT

-- execute your queries for every hour

Set currHour = DATE_ADD(currHour,INTERVAL 1 HOUR);
UNTIL currHour > endhour END REPEAT;
```

if you must use the while loop:

```
WHILE currHour < endhour DO
  -- execute your queries for every hour
  Set currHour = DATE_ADD(currHour,INTERVAL 1 HOUR);
END WHILE;
```

Comment: Hi Sir, it's not working :( I should start in september 20, 2012 and until october 30, 2012 to fetch the query. Please help. Thank you

Comment: What part is not working? If you want to loop between those dates, set the `currHour` and `endhour` accordingly.

Comment: Hi sir, the curr hour will loop in the month of November which is the endtime and not the end hour. Whenever I'll try to run, mysql hangs.

Comment: Try with a smaller duration first. Make sure you have the logic right. you could always process your data in smaller chunks if that big a loop is getting too much for your server.

Comment: HI sir, thank you so much, but I need to insert the result in the a table how can I make it? sorry late to ask you.Anyway, thank you so much it helps me a lot.